# on click of component A function i want to prinnt some data in component B using service

Tags: angular

using git Api i want to fetch entered user id,name in a textbox.

i have component A in which on click of button i am passing a git user name to service and based on that in the same component i am calling that service and printing the details in textbox. now i want to do it with two component , in component a i have a textbox in which the user name will be enter and and button. In the second component i will be printing the details.
Now i do not know how to pass that information to Component B which is i am getting on click of button in component A.

Component A

```
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DetailsComponent } from '../details/details.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdetails',
  templateUrl: './userdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdetails.component.css']
})
export class UserdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

username:string ;
details:any;

  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    //this.searchUserDetails();

  }
searchUserDetails() :void{
  this.details = [];
  this.GituserdetailsService.searchUser(this.username).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
    //console.log(data);
    this.details = data;

  })  ;
  //console.log(this.username);
}
}
```

Component B

```
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
details:any;

  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GituserdetailsService {
   username:String;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    searchUser(username:String) :Observable<any>
   {
     //console.log(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username);
    return this.http.get(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username)

}

}
```

Comment: No i am not able to get the key? what is it could you please tell it according to my question.Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You would have to use `@Input ()` in angular to pass values between components

    An example would be 

    import{ GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
    import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-userdetails',
      templateUrl: './userdetails.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./userdetails.component.css']
    })
    export class UserdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    username:string ;
    details:any;

      constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {

        //this.searchUserDetails();

      }
    searchUserDetails() :void{
      this.details = [];
      this.GituserdetailsService.searchUser(this.username).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
        //console.log(data);
        this.details = data;

      })  ;
      //console.log(this.username);
    }
    }



    import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-details',
      templateUrl: './details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
    })
    export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() details:any;

      constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

    }


Then inside the HTML of ComponentA, you can have 

        <input type="text" > <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

        <componentB *ngIf="details" [details]="details"></ComponentB>

You can read more about it here https://angular.io/api/core/Input
```

Comment: Thanks syntiara i did it before but well thanks for helping

Comment: It should work. What error are you getting? Can you paste your code?

Comment: ```import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { UserdetailsComponent } from '../userdetails/userdetails.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})

export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
 
  @Input('data') data:any;
  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.data);
  }

}```

Comment: Okay. No error here. What's the error you are getting, so I can understand better what the issue might be. You want might want to check your console for errors as well

Comment: i forgot to add input in the import that's the error but now i am done with my task